# How to create a table that contains only the records from "TableA" exclusively?

Tags: join, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I create a [table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pP96GwK2_rBGYjMYnp37OWIRqTHPSxIrqlL-8eiLRyY/edit?usp=sharing) that contains only the records from "Today" which are not in "Last time"?

I have tried this formula, but it returns an N/A.

```
=FILTER(Q22, ISNA(MATCH($Q$9&" "&$R$9, $V$9&" "&$W$9, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using arrayformula?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (a formula in a single cell):

`=FILTER(Q22:T, Q22:Q <> "", ISNA(MATCH(Q22:Q & "♥" & R22:R, V22:V & "♥" & W22:W, 0)))`

[image]

Comment: `"♥"` by mistake?

Comment: @EladBenda No. `♥` is the delimiter (used to avoid collisions), that is a rare symbol (probably won't be in your data) and easy to type (`Alt + NumPad 3`).